ошибка 0xc000007b. Release версия программы, на моём пк запускается и работает. На другом компе возникает ошибка
Речь идёт о запуске .exe, вне среды разработки.
С помощью windeployqt подключил библиотеки.
Программа - 64 разрядная. Библиотеки грузились из C:\Qt\6.7.0\llvm-mingw_64\bin.
Тот пк, где запускается - 64 разрядная система, win 10, Qt установлен.
Пк, где возникает ошибка - 64 разрядная система, win 11, Qt не установлен.
Дополнено: в dependencywalker 100+ красных dll, что с этим можно сделать? На изображении всё, что идет выше - красное.
При запуске с другого компьютера требует еще 3 библиотеки - libstdc++-6, libgcc_s_seh-1, libwinpthread-1. После их добавления - всё та же ошибка 0xc000007b

см. dependencywalker каких либ не хватает

а что делать, если 100+ dll красных?)

Читать вот тут: https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows

сделал всё точно по инструкции, результат остался тот же - на моем пк запускается, на других нет.
могу дополнить: при запуске с другого компьютера требует еще 3 библиотеки - libstdc++-6, libgcc_s_seh-1, libwinpthread-1. После их добавления - всё та же ошибка 0xc000007b

Т.е. зависимости все удовлетворены, но всё равно не запускается?

скажу конкретно - всё, что я сделал после возникновения ошибки:

по данной вами инструкции тупо скопировал все библиотеки из bin в папку с exe-шником.
то же самое и с plugin-ами.
запустил и удалил всё лишнее, проверил работоспособность еще раз - успешно.
на другом ПК подгрузил 3 требуемые библиотеки (скачивал версии для 64bit), после получил ошибку 0xc000007b.

